# Multiple Selection From DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

im trying to select multiple rows/items from a datagrid

```
 <DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="FullRow"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ClientiVS}}"  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ClienteSelezionato}" RowHeaderWidth="0"  EnableColumnVirtualization="False"  CanUserReorderColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="False"   CanUserAddRows="false"  ColumnWidth="*" FontFamily="Agency FB" FontSize="22"  Name="DataGrid1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SelectionChanged="DataGrid1_SelectionChanged" Grid.Row="1" Margin="30,10,30,30">
   
            
   XAML DATAGRID CODE         
            <DataGrid.Columns>


                <DataGridTextColumn  Width="100"  FontFamily="Agency FB" FontSize="20" Header="Nome" Binding="{Binding Nome}"  ></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="100"   FontFamily="Agency FB" FontSize="20" Header="Cognome" Binding="{Binding Cognome}"   ></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="150"  FontFamily="Agency FB" FontSize="20" Header="Indirizzo" Binding="{Binding Indirizzo}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="150"   FontFamily="Agency FB" FontSize="20" Header="Telefono" Binding="{Binding NumeroTelefono}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn  Width="1*"  FontFamily="Agency FB" FontSize="20" Header="Email" Binding="{Binding Email}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn   Header="Selezionato"  Binding="{Binding ClienteSelezionato}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>             
     
        </DataGrid>
```

DATAGRID SELECTIONCHANGED EVENT CODE:

```
public Cliente ClienteSelezionato { get; set; }

private ObservableCollection<Cliente> _ListaClientiSelezionati;

public ObservableCollection<Cliente> ListaClientiSelezionati { get { return _ListaClientiSelezionati; } set { _ListaClientiSelezionati = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ListaClientiSelezionati")); } }



    private void DataGrid1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      
       if (ClienteSelezionato != null   )
        {
            ListaClientiSelezionati.Add(ClienteSelezionato);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that:  if i select two times the same Row from the DataGrid("ClienteSelezionato") it will obviously insert into the list the same item twice. How can i fix it ?

I just want to implement the control that tells me  if an item is already contained in the list ("ListaClientiSelezionati")

Thanks!

Comment: Just clear ListaClientiSelezionati and add all elements from `((DataGrid)sender).SelectedItems`. ListaClientiSelezionati does not need to be an ObservableCollection.

Comment: i will try... the fact is that i need to select multiple Rows from the DataGrid and put it all togetherin the list(ListaClientiSelezionati) so i can send the same Email to the ListaClientiSelezionati list

Comment: All currently selected items will be in the `SelectedItems` property.